# I can't find the javac for versions other than java17

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

I have installed multiple versions of java on my Linux mint mate 20.
I can find the multiple Java versions. But I can't find the multiple *javac* versions, *javac* is only present for Java 17.

I have installed all the Java version using
`sudo apt-get install openjdk-x-jdk`, where `x` is the the Java version.

This is the log of `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1711      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
* 2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1711      manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

This is the log of `sudo update-alternatives --config javac`

```
atul@mintMate:~$ sudo update-alternatives --config javac
There is only one alternative in link group javac (providing /usr/bin/javac): /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
Nothing to configure.
atul@mintMate:~$
```

This is my terminal log

```
atul@mintMate:~$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.1" 2021-10-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.1+12-Ubuntu-120.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.1+12-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
atul@mintMate:~$ javac -version
javac 17.0.1
```

Is there a way to install or locate *javac* in the openjdk-amd64/bin/ folder. As I have already tried to look for them manually using the ***tree*** command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Java 8 install is only for the *Java Runtime Environment* (JRE). Therefore, it won't have a Java compiler (*javac*). The compiler is part of the *Java Development Kit* (JDK).

Try installing Java 8 JDK: `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`. It is likely that your Java 11 distribution is also a JRE-only install. If you need it, just install it the same way as I showed you for Java 8.

Comment: Thanks humble Sir for giving your precious time. This solution worked for me. I thought the other versions were installed by me, but they turned out to be the default ones. So when typed the above command the javac was added also since the java8 was already installed it downloaded just around 25mb.